# background-image not being applied to container div from external css in Flask

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

*****EDIT:**** To Clarify, the path to the image from the first method resolves correctly if entered in the browser. The css in the file is correctly applied to other elements in the DOM so the file is loading correctly. Trying to attach this image to the container div is not working however for some reason**"****

I am trying to set a background image from an external css file in the static directory. The image is stored in a sub directory of the static directory called resources.

The code I am using so far looks like this

```
body {
    background-image:url("127.0.0.1:5000/static/resources/background.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

However this doesn't work and I do not get a "resource not found" error in the console. I am wondering is there any way to use python code in the css file so I can do something like

```
background-image: url( {{ url_for('static', filename="resources/background.png") }} );
```

At the moment this does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

The issue was bootstrap overriding the background style in the container class. I had to create inline css on the template to style the background image in this case

Comment: Did you add the bootstrap CSS file after your custom CSS? If so, you need to switch the files around.

Comment: base.html file extends bootstrap.html. overriding it with external css was problematic so using inline css seems to be the best solution